# Custom recyclerview item android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-xml, recyclerview-layout

I wanted to create the view as shown **below**. this is a view in the horizontal recycler view:

1. the view has a background transparent.
2. With the below code I was able to achieve the view shown in the image.
3. The generated view has background white

[image]

[image]

**Below is the source code for the generated image**, here I have used the coordinator layout as parent layout and relative layout that contains the text and plus icon. An image view to show a human icon. Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="280dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/sixteen_dp"
android:background="@null">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dotted_corner"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/add_user_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="@string/add_user_txt"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/add_user"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/add_user_tv"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/eight_dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_add_new_user"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />/>
</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/civProfilePic"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dotted_circle"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_user_profile_silhoutte_big"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/relativeLayout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

Comment: And what is the question/problem?

Comment: What is the questions???

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: Include your screenshots of the layout. Add both screenshots of what you have and what you want. This will help you get a quicker response. If you do not make your question clear, it'll be downvoted or closed with no response. Also, there is no need for a Relative Layout inside a Coordinator Layout.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to create the view as shown below. this is a view in the
>   horizontal recycler view

i don't see anything sample of `RecyclerView` for your image, it looks like only `ImageView` to pick photo in android storage.

> ..that contains the text and plus icon. An image view to show a human
>   icon.

If you want `Horizontal RecyclerView` with Two Images and one Text:

`"@+id/civProfilePic"`

`"@+id/add_user"`

`"@+id/add_user_tv"`

you have to make class `MyAdapter.class` and `MyContain.class` and please your XML above rename to `my_content.xml`

here the code you need:

please note, this code is using `FirebaseFirestore`

please add this in your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    // Firestore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'

    // Other Firebase
    // don't forget add this in your Manifest.xml , <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0' 
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'

    // Third-party libraries
    // circle image
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

    // cropper if you need cropper when pick image from android storage don't forget this in your Manifest <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.0'

    // reducing size image
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
}
```

**MyContain.class**

```
public class MyContain {

     private String civProfilePic;
     private String add_user;         

     // need Empty contructor
     public MyContain(){}

     public MyContain(String civProfilePic, String add_user){
          this.civProfilePic = civProfilePic;
          this.add_user = add_user;
          // don't enter add_user_tv because the Text should not has any getter method, 
     }

     // get your image using this getter
     public String getCivProfilePic() {return civProfilePic;}

     public String getAddUserIcon() {return add_user;}   

}
```

**MyAdapter.class**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<MyContent> contentList;
    public Context context;

    public MyContain(List<MyContent> contentList){
        this.contentList = contentList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.content_profile_seen_dashboard, parent, false);
        context = parent.getContext();

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);


        // get position of RecyclerView Items and getImage from MyContain class
        String civProfilePic = contentList.get(position).getImage();

        // set photo using String which contain http taken using getImage and load from firestore
        holder.setProfilePhoto(civProfilePic);

        // get position of RecyclerView Items and getAddUserIcon from MyContain class
        String icon_add = contentList.get(position).getAddUserIcon();

        // set icon using String which contain http taken using getAddUserIcon and load from firestore
        holder.setIconAdd(icon_add);



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contentList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private View mView;

        private ImageView civProfilePic;
        private ImageView add_user;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

        }

        public void setProfilePhoto(String image) {

            civProfilePic = mView.findViewById(R.id.civProfilePic);
            RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
            requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.icon_user_profile_silhoutte_big);
            Glide.with(context).applyDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions).load(image).into(civProfilePic);
        }


        public void setIcon(String icon) {

            add_user = mView.findViewById(R.id.add_user);
            RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
            requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.icon_add_new_user);
            Glide.with(context).applyDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions).load(icon).into(add_user);
        }
    }
```

where you want to display recycler view ? Fragment or Activity ?

example, when your recyclerView inside MainActivity.

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView myRecycler;
    private List<MyContent> contentList;
    private MyAdapter myAdapter;
    private Boolean isFirstPageFirstLoad = true;
    private MyContent myContent;

    private FirebaseFirestore firestore;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DocumentSnapshot lastVisible;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        contentList = new ArrayList<>();


        myRecycler = view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(contentList);

        //horizontal recycler
        myRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(container.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

        myRecycler.setAdapter(myAdapter);

}

@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        loadFirstQuery();
    }


    public void loadFirstQuery() {

        contentList.clear();

        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {       

            myRecycler.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                    // horizontal
                    Boolean reachRightSide = !recyclerView.canScrollHorizontally(-1);                  

                    // when recycler reach last right side
                    if (reachRightSide) {
                        loadMorePost();
                    }
                }
            });

            // RETRIEVING PROFILE PHOTOS AND ICONS
            Query firstQuery = firestore
                    .collection("ProfilePhoto")                    
                    .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                    .limit(5);

            firstQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    if (isFirstPageFirstLoad) {
                        lastVisible = documentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(documentSnapshots.size() - 1); 
                    }

                    for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                        if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                            myContent = doc.getDocument().toObject(MyContent.class);

                            if (isFirstPageFirstLoad) {
                                contentList.add(myContent);
                            } else {
                                contentList.add(0, myContent);
                            }

                            // fire the event                            adapterSeen.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }

                    isFirstPageFirstLoad = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }


    public void loadMorePost() {        

        Query nextQuery = firestore
                .collection("ProfilePhoto")                
                .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .startAfter(lastVisible)
                .limit(5);

        nextQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                if (!documentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {

                    lastVisible = documentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(documentSnapshots.size() - 1);
                    for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {

                        if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                            myContent = doc.getDocument().toObject(MyContent.class);
                            contentList.add(myContent);

                            adapterSeen.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

don't forget to this one , please use constraint, it easy to handle

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <FrameLayout        
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/line"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraint">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

once again

**make line.xml in drawable**

this is very tiny line

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            android:color="@color/line"
            android:width="0.5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

in **colors.xml**

```
<color name="line">#f1ecec</color>
```

any question ?